# Run .py script from C++

Tags: python, c++, lua

**My question:**

How to call a python script from C++?

**Context:**

I have such line written in Lua language:

```
os.execute("C:\\InstallPython\\python.exe C:\\FINAM\\py+lua\\Finam_parser.py")
```

It runs a python script from my Lua script. Now, I want to transfer this script from Lua to C++. Please, help me to write the same thing using C++ language and to include the proper libraries.

Comment: I don't know Windows at all, but it would be nice if you could find a way that wasn't so platform (and Python interpreter) specific. On Linux, you can just execute the Python script directly without having to put in the path to the Python interpreter.

Answer (score 5):

Put `#include <cstdlib>` at the top of your program, then put `system("C:\\InstallPython\\python.exe C:\\FINAM\\py+lua\\Finam_parser.py");` wherever you want it to run.

Note that that's a completely literal translation of what `os.execute` does, and that it may be possible to restructure your program to use a cleaner alternative instead.